# can't iterate through dictionary

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON-File with some data in it. Now I try to extract some  of the data, but I always get the error 
*Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Foo\PycharmProjects\youtube_stats\youtube_videos.py", line 29, in 
title = vid["title"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers*

 Here's the code:

```
x= open("results/yt.json", mode="r")
vids = json.load(x)
for vid in vids[channel_id]["video_data"]:
    vid_id = vid
    title = vid["title"]
    date = vid["publishedAt"]
    likes = vid["likeCount"]
    views = ["viewCount"]
    comment_int =["commentCount"]
```

Here's the JSON-File:

```
{
    "Foo": {
        "channel_statistics": {
            "viewCount": "20496906",
            "subscriberCount": "220000",
            "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
            "videoCount": "393"
        },
        "video_data": {
            "video_id": {
                "publishedAt": "2022-04-22T11:34:30Z",
                "channelId": "Foo",
                "title": "Foo",
                "description": "Foo",
                "thumbnails": {
                    "default": {
                        "url": "Foo",
                        "width": 120,
                        "height": 90
                    },
                    "medium": {
                        "url": "Foo",
                        "width": 320,
                        "height": 180
                    },
                    "high": {
                        "url": "Foo",
                        "width": 480,
                        "height": 360
                    }
                },
                "channelTitle": "Foo", 
                "categoryId": "24",
                "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
                "localized": {
                    "title": "Foo",
                    "description": "Foo"
                },
                "defaultAudioLanguage": "de",
                "viewCount": "54991",
                "likeCount": "886",
                "favoriteCount": "0",
                "commentCount": "1276",
                "duration": "PT42M34S",
                "dimension": "2d",
                "definition": "hd",
                "caption": "false",
                "licensedContent": true,
                "contentRating": {},
                "projection": "rectangular"
            },
```

I really can't find a solution, although it's probably very simple...

Comment: title = vid["title"]

Comment: `vid` are the *keys* of the dictionary – i.e. just `video_id`. If you want the `.values()` you have to ask for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's been mentioned in other comments, running `for vid in vids[channel_id]["video_data"]:` will iterate through the dictionary keys. If you'd like to check the contents you can either use the key to access the values, or use `dict.values()` to iterate through the dictionary values.

e.g. 1

```py
for vid in vids[channel_id]["video_data"]:
    title = vids[channel_id]["video_data"][vid]["title"]
```

or

e.g. 2

```py
for vid in vids[channel_id]["video_data"].values():
    title = vid["title"]
```

Check [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more info.